# Calculate days until next birthday in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model with a `date` column called `birthday`.

How would I calculate the number of days until the user's next birthday?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a simple way. You'll want to make sure to catch the case where it's already passed this year (and also the one where it hasn't passed yet)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :birthday

  def days_until_birthday
    bday = Date.new(Date.today.year, birthday.month, birthday.day)
    bday += 1.year if Date.today >= bday
    (bday - Date.today).to_i
  end
end
```

And to prove it! (all I've added is the [timecop gem](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) to keep the calculations accurate as of today (2012-10-16)

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  setup do
    Timecop.travel("2012-10-16".to_date)
  end

  teardown do 
    Timecop.return
  end

  test "already passed" do
    user = User.new birthday: "1978-08-24"
    assert_equal 313, user.days_until_birthday
  end

  test "coming soon" do
    user = User.new birthday: "1978-10-31"
    assert_equal 16, user.days_until_birthday
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 I like yours better than mine :) much more Railsish, and more elegant.  Nice one.

Comment: @will thanks! I'm pretty sure I started with code like yours, wrote the tests, and refactored until I liked how it looked.

Comment: If someone was born on a leap day, `Date.new(Date.today.year, birthday.month, birthday.day)` will raise an exception on a non-leap year.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
require 'date'

def days_to_next_bday(bday)
  d = Date.parse(bday)

  next_year = Date.today.year + 1
  next_bday = "#{d.day}-#{d.month}-#{next_year}"

 (Date.parse(next_bday) - Date.today).to_i
end

puts days_to_next_bday("26-3-1985")
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a swipe at this:

```
require 'date'
bday = Date.new(1973,10,8)  // substitute your records date here.
this_year  = Date.new(Date.today.year,   bday.month, bday.day )
if this_year > Date.today 
  puts this_year - Date.today
else
   puts Date.new(Date.today.year + 1,   bday.month, bday.day ) - Date.today
end
```

I'm not sure if Rails gives you anything that makes that much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to approach this with lesser-known methods, but they make the code more self-explanatory.
Also, this works with birth dates on a February 29th.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :birthday

  def next_birthday
    options = { year: Date.today.year }
    if birthday.month == 2 && birthday.day == 29 && !Date.leap?(Date.today.year)
      options[:day] = 28
    end
    birthday.change(options).tap do |next_birthday|
      next_birthday.advance(years: 1) if next_birthday.past?
    end
  end
end
```

And of course, the number of days until the next birthday is:

```
(user.next_birthday - Date.today).to_i
```